# Layer or hierarchy problem for GameObject

Tags: unity-game-engine, hierarchy, prefab, setparent

In my Unity project, I made a prefab to rendering images from web sources by URL. However, when testing the app, it displayed the images like this:

[image]

There are two image windows, but you can see, the image in the first opened window is floating over the second opened window, but under the second image.

The window (**ImageHolder**) is a prefab I made, and in this prefab, I made another prefab (**ImageBox**) to rendering image. Here is the prefab hierarchy below.

[image]

Here is my script to call to open the instances, the look up `imageExtensions` part is the part to call this image window. the `else` part is open web sources with browser, this part works fine.

```
 void OpenLinks(string url, string name)
    {
        int l = 100; int m = -600;

        // Find if the media in URL with type of media via extension
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(url);

        // Array of media extensions
        string[] imageExtensions = { ".jpg", ".png", ".gif", "jpeg", "jfif", "svg", "webp" };
        string[] videoExtensions = { ".mp4", ".avi", ".mov", "webm" };
        string[] audioExtensions = { ".mp3", ".wav", ".aac" };

        if (Array.Exists(imageExtensions, element => extension.Equals(element, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
        {
            GameObject image = Instantiate(imageHolder, _nextWindowPosition, imageHolder.transform.rotation);
            image.SetActive(true);

            // Find the imageBox component and add a SpriteRenderer component
            GameObject imageBox = image.transform.Find("ImageBackground/ImageBox").gameObject;
            SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer = imageBox.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

            TextMeshProUGUI title = image.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>();

            image.transform.SetParent(Windows.transform, false);
            image.name = name;
            title.text = name;

            _nextWindowPosition += new Vector2(50f, -50f);
            if (_nextWindowPosition.x > 150)
                _nextWindowPosition.x = 50f;
            if (_nextWindowPosition.y < -600)
                _nextWindowPosition.y = -50f;

            GameObject imageBackground = image.transform.Find("ImageBackground").gameObject;
            GameObject controlButtons = image.transform.Find("ControlButtons").gameObject;

            StartCoroutine(LoadImage(url, spriteRenderer, imageBackground, controlButtons));
        }
        else if (Array.Exists(videoExtensions, element => extension.Equals(element, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
        {

        }
        else if (Array.Exists(audioExtensions, element => extension.Equals(element, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
        {
        }
        else
        {
            GameObject browser = Instantiate(browserWindow, _nextWindowPosition, browserWindow.transform.rotation);
            browser.SetActive(true);

            // Find the browser2D component
            GameObject browser2D = browser.transform.Find("BrowserBackground/Browser2D").gameObject;

            TextMeshProUGUI title = browser.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>();

            browser2D.GetComponent<SimpleWebBrowser.WebBrowser2D>().Navigate(url);
            browser.transform.SetParent(Windows.transform, false);
            browser.name = name;
            title.text = name;

            //RectTransform rectTransform = browser.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
            //rectTransform.position = new Vector2(l, m);
            _nextWindowPosition += new Vector2(50f, -50f);
            if (_nextWindowPosition.x > 150)
                _nextWindowPosition.x = 50f;
            if (_nextWindowPosition.y < -600)
                _nextWindowPosition.y = -50f;
        }
    }
```

Comment: There're many factors affect the rendering order: shader, bounding box and draw call batching. Your description hardly explains these details.

Comment: There are 2 things you can try first: 1. disable draw call batching, 2. adjust the position of the renderers in the hierarchy window.